Number of LR(0) item sets of the grammar (Dragon Book, exercise 4.6.7)
I'm stuck on exercise 4.6.7 part b from the dragon book. The task is to show that the given grammar Gn:

S → Aibi        for 1 ≤ i ≤ nAi → ajAi | aj   for 1 ≤ i,j ≤ n i≠j

has 2n + n2 + n LR(0) item sets.
It follows that G3 must have 23 + 32 + 3 = 20 LR(0) sets. However, when I manually construct LR sets for the grammar G3 I get 23 sets. Grammophone gives the same result. Here they are:

 I1   S' → •S   S  → •A1b1 
     A1  → •a2A1     A1  → •a2     A1  → •a3A1     A1  → •a3   S  → •A2b2     A2  → •a1A2     A2  → •a1     A2  → •a3A2     A2  → •a3 
    S  → •A3b3     A3  → •a1A3     A3  → •a1     A3  → •a2A3     A3  → •a2  
I2   S' → S•I3   S  → A1•b1I4   S  → A2•b2I5   S  → A3•b3I6   S  → A1b1•I7   S  → A2b2•I8   S  → A3b3•I9     A2  → a1•A2       A2  → •a1A2       A2  → •a1       A2  → •a3A2       A2  → •a3     A2  → a1•     A3  → a1•A3       A3  → •a1A3       A3  → •a1       A3  → •a2A3       A3  → •a2     A3  → a1•I10     A1  → a2•A1       A1  → •a2A1       A1  → •a2       A1  → •a3A1       A1  → •a3     A1  → a2•     A3  → a2•A3       A3  → •a1A3       A3  → •a1       A3  → •a2A3       A3  → •a2     A3  → a2•I11     A1  → a3•A1       A1  → •a2A1       A1  → •a2       A1  → •a3A1       A1  → •a3     A1  → a3•     A2  → a3•A2       A2  → •a1A2       A2  → •a1       A2  → •a3A2       A2  → •a3     A2  → a3•I12     A2  → a1•A2       A2  → •a1A2       A2  → •a1       A2  → •a3A2       A2  → •a3     A2  → a1•I13     A3  → a1•A3       A3  → •a1A3       A3  → •a1       A3  → •a2A3       A3  → •a2     A3  → a1•I14     A1  → a2•A1       A1  → •a2A1       A1  → •a2       A1  → •a3A1       A1  → •a3     A1  → a2•I15     A3  → a2•A3       A3  → •a1A3       A3  → •a1       A3  → •a2A3       A3  → •a2     A3  → a2•I16     A1  → a3•A1       A1  → •a2A1       A1  → •a2       A1  → •a3A1       A1  → •a3     A1  → a3•I17     A2  → a3•A2       A2  → •a1A2       A2  → •a1       A2  → •a3A2       A2  → •a3     A2  → a3•I18     A1  → a2A1•I19     A1  → a3A1•I20     A2  → a1A2•I21     A2  → a3A2•I22     A3  → a1A3•I23     A3  → a2A3•

I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong. Anyone who has solved this exercise, please advise where I'm going wrong and, if possible, the correct solution.
Thanks.
